# Printing Array of Strings

Tags: c, arrays, parsing

I'm parsing a text file:

```
Hello, this is a text file.
```

and creating by turning the file into a char[]. Now I want to take the array, iterate through it, and create an array of arrays that splits the file into words:

```
 string[0] = Hello
 string[1] = this
 string[2] = is
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "TextReader.h"
#include <ctype.h>

void printWord(char *string) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i ++)
    printf("%c", string[i]);
printf("\n");
}

void getWord(char *string) {
char sentences[5][4];
int i;
int letter_counter = 0;
int word_counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i ++) {
            // Checks if the character is a letter
    if (isalpha(string[i])) {
        sentences[word_counter][letter_counter] = string[i];
        letter_counter++;
    } else {
        sentences[word_counter][letter_counter + 1] = '\0';
        word_counter++;
        letter_counter = 0;
    }
}

// This is the code to see what it returns:
i = 0;
for (i; i < 5; i ++) {
    int a = 0;
    for (a; a < 4; a++) {
        printf("%c", sentences[i][a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main() {
    // This just returns the character array. No errors or problems here.
char *string = readFile("test.txt");

getWord(string);

return 0;
}
```

This is what it returns:

```
Hell
o
this
is
a) w
```

I suspect this has something to do with pointers and stuff. I come from a strong Java background so I'm still getting used to C.

Comment: Have a look at strtok - it already splits char* strings up into smaller parts, based on the supplied delimiters. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106765/using-strtok-in-c This answer is exactly the answer that I wanted. However, some of the syntax is confusing. Nonetheless, it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

With `sentences[5][4]` you're limiting the number of `sentences` to 5 and the length of each word to 4. You'll need to make it bigger in order to process more and longer words. Try `sentences[10][10]`. You're also not checking if your input words aren't longer than what `sentences` can handle. With bigger inputs this can lead to heap-overflows & acces violations, remember that C does not check your pointers for you!

Of course, if you're going to use this method for bigger files with bigger words you'll need to make it bigger [or allocate it dymanically](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Answer (score 0):

sample that do not use strtok:

```
void getWord(char *string){
    char buff[32];
    int letter_counter = 0;
    int word_counter = 0;
    int i=0;
    char ch;

    while(!isalpha(string[i]))++i;//skip
    while(ch=string[i]){
        if(isalpha(ch)){
            buff[letter_counter++] = ch;
            ++i;
        } else {
            buff[letter_counter] = '\0';
            printf("string[%d] = %s\n", word_counter++, buff);//copy to dynamic allocate array
            letter_counter = 0;
            while(string[++i] && !isalpha(string[i]));//skip
        }
    }
}
```

use strtok version:

```
void getWord(const char *string){
    char buff[1024];//Unnecessary if possible change
    char *p;
    int word_counter = 0;

    strcpy(buff, string);
    for(p=buff;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, " ,."));p=NULL){//delimiter != (not isaplha(ch))
        printf("string[%d] = %s\n", word_counter++, p);//copy to dynamic allocate array
    }
}
```