# quiz questions from txt file into array in c

Tags: c, arrays, netbeans, struct, int

I am trying to get the line below into an array in c.  this is for a quiz program that asks 10 questions (out of possible 15) in a random order and tracks the score and tells the user at the end how they did.

here is an example of the format for one line in my text file:

**what is not an official language in Canada;English;French;Spanish;3**

in other words format is string;string;string;string;int

or

question;choice-a;choice-b;choice-c;correct answer

I know how to read a file line by line in C but I do not know how to utilize these ; to divide up one line into multiple lines.  Also, not sure how to keep score for this quiz after user selects their choice as an int and presses enter.

Apparently, I am supposed to define a struct to present these questions...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Yes, this is for a final project but lectures now are over and our teacher will not provide anymore help to students outside of class hours.

Here is what I have done so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8LtH.png

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for a class, I don't know if your instructor wants you to use low-tech methods or not, but I would use something like sscanf for a problem like this.  You can do something like this:

```
int number;
char fruit[16];
char line[]="I ate 3 bananas.";
sscanf(line, "I ate %d %s.", &number, fruit);
```

And it updates the variables that you point to within the sscanf function accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I add a screen shot to my original question so everyone can see what I am working on.  The instructor wants a basic c program but it has to be elegant for full marks. my struggle is combining all these components together. like how do I execute for example char line[] = and then I would have to read "I ate 3 bananas."; from a file instead of it being typed on in the program.  But the screen will tell all that I trying to get done with comments of program requirements line by line.

Answer (score 1):

As this is for a class project, I will provide only general guidance.  I would suggest you review the `strtok` function, using the line from your text file as the string and a ";" as the token.  Examples and documentation are available [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).  Repeated calls to this function will allow you to divide your line up into segments.

As for the struct requirement, a sensible way would be to create a struct with these members:

1. A string (char*) containing the question.
2. An array of strings containing the choices.
3. An int defining the number of choices (i.e. the length of the array in 2).  You might be able to hard-code this to 3 in your example.
4. An int defining the correct answer.

You would create an instance of the struct for each line in your text file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added a link to my original question so you can see what I am looking at.  I created the struct with members but I am not sure how to create then an array of strings? So for example if there are 10 questions that need to be asked at random out of 15 possible questions does my array have to be 15 "things" long?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably a tokenizer.
You may want to have a look at the discussion here [Using strtok in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106765/using-strtok-in-c). A few snippet of code are listed which in my opinion, is very helpful in your case.