# can you make string to array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Hey I'm currently learning c language. Is there any possibility to turn `char*` type variable, which contains some words separated by spaces into an array of string(in c it's `char*[]`) that way that each word on the original variable will be in different index in the new array?

Comment: Search for `strtok()`.

Comment: Check out the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106765/using-strtok-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C library Function [strtok()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):**

**char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
     printf ("%s\n",pch);
     pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I thought there isn't a string type on c language?.. and in the first example can you edit it that way that it will put the tokens into an array of chars?

Comment: yep it divides the char[] based on the delimiter you provided to the function. For further info please visit the link

Comment: You splitted array into tokens. I asked to spilt (char*) type to array.

Comment: @UmerFarooq: the "manual method" does not make any sense as it copies every character of `str` to `tokens`. The OP asked for splitting `char *str` to `char *array[numTokens]` or so.

Comment: @harpun yep at first I thought it was C++ question so I used string in place of char[], later removed that. thanks for pointing that out :)