# Finding words with the same first character

Tags: c, arrays, string, strncmp

I've made an array and now I'm trying to compare first symbols of two strings and if it's true to print that word. But I got a problem:

> Incompatible types in assignmentof "int" to "char"[20]"

Here is the code:

```
for ( wordmas= 0; i < character; i++ )
{
  do {
    if (!strncmp(wordmas[i], character, 1)
  }
  puts (wordmas[i]);
}
```

Maybe you guys could help me?

Comment: Which line does the error message correspond to?  What are the declarations of all the variables involved?

Comment: I'm sorry your code doesn't make any sense. What is that `do` block doing there? What is the `if` controlling? Please show the types of everything.

Comment: you have syntax error

Comment: what is type of `wordmas`? you should write your whole code or at least types of variables mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You do not need `strncmp` to compare the first character - all you need is a simple `==` or `!=`.
- Using a `do` without a `while` is a syntax error; you do not need a nested loop to solve your problem.
- `character` is used to limit the progress of `i` in the outer loop, and also to compare to the first character of a word in `wordmas[i]`. This is very likely a mistake.
- Assuming that `wordmas` is an array, assigning to `wordmas` in the loop header is wrong.

The code to look for words that start in a specific character should look like this:

```
char wordmas[20][20];
... // read 20 words into wordmas
char ch = 'a'; // Look for all words that start in 'a'
// Go through the 20 words in an array
for (int i = 0 ; i != 20 ; i++) {
    // Compare the first characters
    if (wordmas[i][0] == ch) {
        ... // The word wordmas[i] starts in 'a'
    }
}
```